# New Row and Particular Cell

Tags: jquery

I have a table as below. I'm getting JSON from more than API. As I get the data I need to insert a new row in my table.

I've seen I can use something like - which i'd want to enter in the 2nd cell (tr with id second):

```
$('#failuresTable > tbody > tr').eq(i-1).after(jsonData.reports[0]);
```

however its not working.

Any ideas?

```
<table id="failuresTables"> 
                <thead> 
                    <tr> 
                        <th>Name</th> 
                        <th>Description</th> 
                        <th>Reason</th> 
                        <th>Header</th>
                        <th>Screen</th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead> 
                <tbody> 
                    <tr> 
                    <td id="first"></td> 
                    <td id="second"></td> 
                    <td id="third"></td> 
                    <td id="fourth"></td> 
                </tr>
                </tbody> 
            </table>
```

Comment: What is `i` in context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `failuresTable` to `failuresTables` in your HTML code.

Comment: Hi, that doesnt work. Don't I need to specify <tr> anywhere as my table has multiple headers/columns.

Comment: Also Want to ask if i had a for loop how do i force a new <tr> because at the moment it just adds the results to the end

Comment: No. I have for loop which gets names. Once it gets a name I want to insert it one at time into a new row of the table

Comment: Can you ask as `new question` with description what exactly you want?